# Spring Resful WS issue

Tags: eclipse, spring, rest, maven

I'm following http://www.java2blog.com/2015/09/spring-restful-web-services-json-example.html and as it's suggested in the article when I deploy my application to tomcat I get the warning:
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:restordering' did not find a matching property. 
(restordering is my application context)
And when I try to access my application I get this warning:
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/restordering] in DispatcherServlet with name 'restordering'
and I see a 404 error page!
I've tested this on tomcat 7 and 8. I've created the war and deployed outside of eclipse and followed all suggested solution including change in server definition (publish module context to separate XML files) and removing and adding and doing all the tricks it's described in the above article and on stackoverflow but nothing has worked so far.
Before I get "this is a warning and ..." yes it is a warning but also I get 404 error and can't access my services.
And yes I have the correct package name in my restordering-servlet.xml (    context:component-scan base-package="com.obp.restordering.controller" ).

As requested here is my web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>restordering</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>restordering</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and restordering-servlet.xml is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.obp.restordering.controller" />
</beans>
```

and my controller file is this:

```
package com.obp.restordering.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.obp.restordering.bean.Country;

@RestController
public class CountryController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/countries", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();
        listOfCountries = createCountryList();
        return listOfCountries;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/country/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public Country getCountryById(@PathVariable int id) {
        List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();
        listOfCountries = createCountryList();

        for (Country country : listOfCountries) {
            if (country.getId() == id)
                return country;
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Utiliy method to create country list.
    public List<Country> createCountryList() {
        Country indiaCountry = new Country(1, "India");
        Country chinaCountry = new Country(4, "China");
        Country nepalCountry = new Country(3, "Nepal");
        Country bhutanCountry = new Country(2, "Bhutan");

        List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();
        listOfCountries.add(indiaCountry);
        listOfCountries.add(chinaCountry);
        listOfCountries.add(nepalCountry);
        listOfCountries.add(bhutanCountry);
        return listOfCountries;
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hi...try to post your web.xml and spring context configuration so we may have more information about the issue (if related to some bad configuration)

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing but I need to come clean and admit and provide an answer so if others have the same issue they don't circle around days as I did.
Arpit the author of the mentioned tutorial responded to my request for help and after checking my code confirmed all works as expected!
The issue was in how I was trying to access my service!  If I go to /restordering/countries I get the 404 error. To access the service I need to go to /restordering/restordering/countries! As simple as that. 
The warnings I still get and I can't resolve them at this time but at least the service is working and this seems more of a deployment/setting issue than actual spring development issue.
Anyways, I thought this may help some others.

Cheers